# C# How to sanitize a string of XSS?

Tags: c#

What is the most reliable or well developed library in C# for sanitizing HTML data for XSS? I'd rather not use a full framework just to do this. Maybe a library isn't even needed? I'd rather not do my own regex implementation even if its copying and pasting regex that is proven to work, surely there's a library out there.

PHP has [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to prevent XSS, it is only used for output data without doing anything to stored data. Does C# have something like this?

Comment: XSS is not the same as sql injection. To protect yourself from sql injection all you need is to use proper parameterized queries. I haven't written for web platforms for a long time so for XSS all I remember is to try and remove the <javascript> tags.

Comment: @el_pup_le You can check my post. It would help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XSS attack, a hacker can injects malicious JavaScript code into web pages which will be executed in the client browser.

You can try following ways:

- The text should be `HTML encoded` before being added to the DOM.
- The X-XSS-Protection header should be used to enable XSS filters on
  the browser: `X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"`
- Something like `TempData` should be used to pass data between views instead of parameters in which attacker can inject malicious JavaScript code

[Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) is a good article about preventing XSS attacks

Comment: thanks, i'm using angular 2 so I think I'm safe with the XSS

Comment: Protecting the frontend is only one part of XSS prevention. Ideally you must protect your database as well. This might not be always the case but if you have a data layer (i.e. a backend for your app, or a database behind) and if you're not %100 certain that your app will be the only app that accesses that data, you might still be vulnerable to XSS.

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> What is the most reliable or well developed library in C# for sanitizing HTML data for XSS?

The accepted answer does not address this, so I'll put forward the following, which (as of 2023) is in active development, and has 1.4k stars on GH, and 34M downloads on Nuget:

[mganss/HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer)

Looks like it's responsible for just html sanitization, like the question requests, and is well supported.